# Insert function with condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert values into a `table_A` from `table_B` where some conditions are met. Here is what I want to do but does not work:

```
insert into table_A(ID, value1, value2)
select ID, value1, value2
from table_B
where table_B.ID <> table_A.ID
```

I am getting this error:

> *The multi-part identifier "table_A.ID" could not be bound*

thanks

Comment: You haven't declared how table_B's rows are related to table_A.  What you probably meant to do is this:  `WHERE table_B.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_A)`

Comment: You're not actually selecting the table_A values anywhere. You could use a `WHERE EXISTS` with an additional select statement. That's just one way of doing it. If you look up JOIN vs IN vs EXISTS there is quite a bit of discussion on the topic as far as efficiency.

Comment: @user1858332 Please take some efforts. This type of question already been asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work like that. You are not joining the tables in an insert statement. Use

```
insert into table_A(ID, value1, value2)
select ID, value1, value2
from table_B
where ID not in (select ID from table_A)
```

Comment: I am deleting my answer as it just exact replica of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a right join is faster

```
insert into table_A (ID, value1, value2)
select b.* 
  from table_b b
       right join table_a a
         on  a.ID = b.ID
 where a.ID is null
```

As this is a common problem the MERGE statement was introduced in SQL2003 standard. You can update existing rows, insert new ones and delete others depending on a specific condition.

```
merge into table_a a 
  using table_B b 
    on (a.ID=b.ID)
when not matched then
  insert (ID, value1, value2) 
  values (b.ID, b.value1, b.value2)
```

(untested)